# Is there common way to run multiple robots in ROS2?

Tags: ros2, tf2, namespaces, tf-prefix, multiple

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The hard part is `/tf`  since `robot_state_publisher` push all `frame_id`s into single topic.

EDIT:
This is how I launch RobotStatePublisher:

```
robot_state_publisher = Node(
    package='robot_state_publisher',
    node_executable='robot_state_publisher',
    node_namespace=LaunchConfiguration(args.MODEL_NAME_ARG),
    output='screen',
    parameters=[{
        'use_sim_time': LaunchConfiguration(args.USE_SIM_TIME_ARG, default=True),
        'tf_prefix': 'ssss',
    }],
    arguments=[
        urdf,
        LaunchConfiguration(args.MODEL_NAME_ARG),
        '__log_level:=warn',
        'tf_prefix:=dddd',
    ],
)
```

`tf_prefix` is not set neither as parameter, nor as argument.

If you look into `dashing` branch of `robot_state_publisher`, you can see that `tf_prefix` is actually ignored:
https://github.com/ros2/robot_state_publisher/blob/bffb9d14c7452df0a96b92cd338c4137ec6e39b7/src/joint_state_listener.cpp#L83

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/334501/is-there-common-way-to-run-multiple-robots-in-ros2?/) by [Dmitriy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45566/dmitriy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2019-10-03

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I opened PR on this.
https://github.com/ros2/robot_state_publisher/pull/34

---

Originally posted by [Dmitriy](https://answers.ros.org/users/45566/dmitriy/) with karma: 78 on 2019-10-04

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For any new viewers to this question, the functionality of `tf_prefix` has been recently reintroduced in [Foxy](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/170) and [Galactic](https://github.com/ros/robot_state_publisher/pull/171), under a new name: `frame_prefix`. More details can be found on the [wiki here](https://index.ros.org/p/robot_state_publisher/github-ros-robot_state_publisher/#galactic)

---

Originally posted by [shonigmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/69938/shonigmann/) with karma: 1567 on 2021-10-12

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1